# MySQL filter on step

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
create table
(
 col1 int,
 nr   int
);

insert into table (col1, nr) values (1, 1);
insert into table (col1, nr) values (2, 1);
insert into table (col1, nr) values (3, 1);

insert into table (col1, nr) values (10, 2);
insert into table (col1, nr) values (208, 2);

insert into table (col1, nr) values (356, 3);

... 

insert into table (col1, nr) values (43, 10000);
insert into table (col1, nr) values (34, 10000);
```

According to this example the max(nr) = 10000. How to have query that will filter the data in above table in the following way:

```
count on (col1) for nr between 1 and 20, the 20 is the step
count on (col1) for nr between 21 and 40
count on (col1) for nr between 41 and 60
...
count on (col1) for nr between X and 10000
```

**This is what I need, thanks:**

```
select 
rownum,
((rownum -1) * 100) + 1 as p_nr_token_start,
rownum * 100 as p_nr_token_end
from (
select 
 @rn:=@rn+1 as rownum
from information_schema.columns a,
(select @rn:=0) b) rr
where (rownum * 100) <= 100000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
select
  sum(case when nr between 1 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) as step_1_20,
  sum(case when nr between 21 and 40 then 1 else 0 end) as step_21_40,
  sum(case when nr between 41 and 60 then 1 else 0 end) as step_41_60,
  ...
  sum(case when nr between 9981 and 10000 then 1 else 0 end) as step_9981_10000
from table
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/343a1/2

Instead of creating this by hand, you can use a stored procedure to create a dynamic SQL query and executing it. Example of preparing dynamic statement is here: https://irhowto.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/mysql-stored-procedure-prepared-statements-and-sql-injection/

EDIT:
    delimiter //

```
create procedure get_data()
begin
    declare max_number int default 10000;
    declare number_counter int default 0;
    set @s = 'select ';
    while number_counter < max_number do
        set @s = concat(@s,
            case when number_counter = 0 then '' else ',' end,
            'sum(case when nr between ', number_counter + 1,
            ' and ', number_counter + 20, ' then 1 else 0 end) '
            ' as step_', number_counter + 1,
            '_', number_counter + 20);
        set number_counter = number_counter + 20;
    end while;
    set @s = concat(@s, ' from test');
    prepare stmt from @s;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
end //

delimiter ;

call get_data();
```

This stored procedure will get you what you want. You will get 500 columns, which may be really impractical to use.

Comment: no, I don't want to write all this manually, having N time sum(case when nr between 1 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) ...

Comment: I can help you with a stored procedure, if that's what you want